# What came first, the destructor or delete() ? C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, destructor, new-operator, delete-operator

Many answers on this site mentions that `delete()` calls destructor. But the sample code below seems to call `delete()` inside the destructor. What is the correct usage of delete() when object is initialized in stack and in heap?

[Click for the source.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smart-pointers-cpp/)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
class SmartPtr {
    int* ptr; // Actual pointer
public:
    // Constructor: Refer https:// www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-93/
    // for use of explicit keyword
    explicit SmartPtr(int* p = NULL) { ptr = p; }
 
    // Destructor
    ~SmartPtr() { delete (ptr); }
 
    // Overloading dereferencing operator
    int& operator*() { return *ptr; }
};
 
int main()
{
    SmartPtr ptr(new int());
    *ptr = 20;
    cout << *ptr;
 
    // We don't need to call delete ptr: when the object
    // ptr goes out of scope, the destructor for it is automatically
    // called and destructor does delete ptr.
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your confusion comes from the fact that this program deals with _two_ objects: the `SmartPtr` and the `int` it is managing the memory of. `~SmartPtr()` calls `delete` on the `int`, not on itself.

Comment: It's not deleting itself in the constructor, so there is nothing to be confused about.

Comment: @user207421 it's a universal human right to be confused, not yours to decide about who's confused by what ;)

Comment: @YSC Thank you for your kind answer. As a second question, isn't `ptr` inside `class SmartPtr()` automatically deleted once the destructor of `class SmartPtr()` is called even when we don't call `delete(ptr)` inside the destructor?

Comment: @YSC It is also a universal human right to deconfuse someone by analysis. If you think otherwise please provide justification for *both* propositions.

Comment: On case of raw pointer there are nothing automatic. Pointers can point at objects (or members or elements of objects) not owned by the containing class. So deleting a pointer in destructor is needed by your program logic that SmartPtr owns that int, and that is not known to compiler.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thank you. So by `delete()` I am not deleting the pointer itself (in other words the connection to the object) but the actual object `ptr` points to (i.e. the pointe**e**). Actually, it would not make sense to delete the connection to the object while whole `class SmartPtr()` is already being deleted.

Comment: @Xfce4   In short, no.  If you don't do `delete ptr` inside your destructor, the object pointed to by `ptr` is never destroyed.   Unlike some other (garbage-collected) languages, there is no implicit cleanup of dynamically allocated objects in C++.      Informally, if you remove the `delete ptr` from your destructor, the object (of type `int` in your code) is said to be leaked (no pointers point at it, so no code in your program can find the object and, if your program cannot find the object, your program cannot destroy it).

Comment: @Peter I was about to ask this: *What if there is single thread and `ptr` is the only pointer to the object? Do I still need to call `delete(ptr)` or the object pointed by `ptr` will be deleted automatically?* Then the following question arose: *What if `anotherPtr` is to claim the abandoned object in some time in the future? Would calling the destructor of the pointed object automatically -before the scope ends- be that beneficial?*

Comment: `delete` calls the destructor, always. But whether a destructor calls `delete` or not depends on how it is coded. The error here usually is that beginners expect pointers to be deleted automatically in some circumstances. That is never true, pointers do not have destructors.

Comment: @Xfce4 - This has nothing to do with threads. But if your system has an operating systems, that will surely reclaim the memory when the program terminates. So it is not a "permanent" leak, unless th program runs a server 24/7. `anotherPtr` cannot claim the leaked object later, because it doesn't know where to find it.

Comment: @BoP I mentioned threads because I thought that when there are multiple threads, the object pointed by `ptr` could be running some tasks which require it to be not deleted automatically.

Comment: @Xfce4  There is no mechanism in standard C++ for `anotherPtr` to claim the "abandoned object".  Regardless of whether the program is single threaded or multithreaded.    With modern operating systems, memory is reclaimed by the operating system as the program terminates, but that is outside the realms of standard C++  (it is an implementation detail of the operating system itself).

Comment: Then the destructor better block until the task is completed or a timeout passes. You can run any code in a destructor.

Comment: For the real code (not the provided minimal example — to which, thank you for that), you'd want to handle copy constructor and copy assignment, and may want to also provide a move constructor and move assignment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the destructor `SmartPtr` gets the control

```
 ~SmartPtr() { delete (ptr); }
```

its body is executed. Within the body there is used the operator delete that is executed. If the pointer `ptr` would point to an object of a class type then the destructor of the class would be in turn called before freeing the dynamically allocated memory for the object.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        ~A() { std::cout << "A::~A() called\n"; }
    };

    struct B
    {
        B() : ptr( new A ) {};
        ~B()
        {
            std::cout << "B::~B() called\n";
            delete ptr;
        }
        A *ptr;
    };

    { 
        B b; 
    }

    std::cout << "That is all!\n";
}
```

The program output is

```
B::~B() called
A::~A() called
That is all!
```

If to remove within the destructor of the class `B` this statement

```
delete ptr;
```

then objects of the class B will  produce memory leaks because dynamically allocated objects of the class `A` will not be destroyed and the occupied memory by them will not be freed.